# IIFE in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Recently, while writing a business card site, in order to create a gallery, I used JavaScript. I created the `window.number` variable in it, but realized that in this case it is better to avoid the global variable. In search for a solution, I came across IIFE. So, I would like to know how exactly the construct `(function(){ })()` works in JS

I tried to use IIFE, succeeded, but without understanding what I am doing.

Comment: Read [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression)

Comment: Or the [Glossary entry on MDN](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/IIFE).